# Assigning Values to the neighbors same value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, signal-processing, data-analysis

I am having a small issue but I am clueless where I am at fault. Can someone please guide me the right way? Thanks in advance.

What I have done.

My codes finds local maxima’s.

Bring down from local maxima to a certain point.

Assign the neighbors that are greater than the downsized value, the value of downsized point.

**Small Example**

```
X = [1 0 1 4.3 4.5 5 4.3 4.2 0 0 0 2 6.2 6.3 7 6.2 7.4 8 7.2 1 2 3 4 2];
```

Local maxima’s are 5, 7, 8, and 4

Go down to certain point. Like 4, 6, 7, 3.

Assign neighbors that have values greater than 4,6,7,3 same values.

**Output will be like**

```
X = [1 0 1 4 4 4 4 4 0 0 0 2 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1 2 3 3 2];
```

**As this was a simple example so did not have much difference when I applied my code on it.**

I have provided another example with my code. Please have a look at that.

```
 t = 50;
 X = sin(2*pi*10*(1:t)/t) + 0.5*sin(2*pi*5*(1:50)/t) - linspace(0,3,50);

 % plot(X)
 A= X;
 %   A1 = [1 0 1 4.3 4.5 5 4.3 4.2 0 0 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6  6 1 2 3 4 2];
 [pks,locs] = findpeaks(A);
 idx = A(locs)-0.3  ; % will bring local maxima to the point where we want 

 for b = 1: numel(idx)  % loop for checking idx 
 for c = 1:numel(A)  % loop for checking neighbourhoods

  if (A(locs(1,b)-c)> idx(1,b) && A(locs(1,b)+c)> idx(1,b))

  else  
      d= c-1;
      z(b)= d;
     break
  end


  end
  end
  for i = 1:numel(idx)

  for n = 1:z(1,i)
       idx_1 = A(locs(i) - n); % will find what is in neighbourhood of local   maxima
        idx_2 = A(locs(i) + n);
 %         idx_1 = A(locs - n); % will find what is in neighbourhood of local maxima
 %         idx_2 = A(locs + n);
    if (idx_1>idx(1,i) && (idx_2>idx(1,i)))  % Check and assign the same value to neighbourhood of local maxima
       A(locs(1,i)) = idx(i);
       A(locs(1,i)-n) = idx(i);
       A(locs(1,i)+n) = idx(i);
%            A(i)) = A(idx(i))
   else if (idx_1 < idx(1,i) && (idx_2>idx(1,i)))
        A(locs(1,i)) = idx(i);
        A(locs(1,i)+n) = idx(i);   
       else if (idx_1 > idx(1,i) && (idx_2<idx(1,i)))
        A(locs(1,i)) = idx(i);
        A(locs(1,i)-n) = idx(i);        
       else
        A(locs(1,i)) = idx(i); 
        A(locs(1,i)-n) = idx_1(i);
        A(locs(1,i)+n) = idx_1(i);
       end
      end

  end
  end
         A(locs(1,i)) = idx(i);
  end

  figure(1)
  hold on 
  plot(X,'r')
  plot(A,'b')
  hold off
```

**Expected Output be like Black line in the picture not blue lines that are formed from code**

[image]

Comment: In your example figure the black line cannot be achieved, as your x axis values/ ticks are going from 1 to 50 in steps of 1. So you cannot have nodes at 5.5 and 6.5.

Comment: Irreducible Thanks a lot for your help and time . It worked after adding more points for time means time steps.

Comment: In your small example, 7.4 is a neighbor of 8 in the input, but it gets lowered to 6. Why? It is not clear to me exactly how you define neighbors.

Comment: Actually I want to lower my peaks upto a certain value and assign them the value of lowered points.
Yes 7.4 is neighbourhood of 8 but I want it to be lowered to small value of local maxima that’s why I have tried to assign it value of 6 which is small value of lowered local maxima than 8.
You are right but for my application I need to do this. Thanks a lot for noticing it and your time to have a look at my query.