# Median filter at point of local maximas in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, signal-processing, median

Is it possible for me to apply median filter only at points of local maxima’s.

Like in my simple example local maxima is 5,7,8,4.

Can I apply median filter at these points. I have also provided code with sin signal to understand the effect of median filter better.

Can I apply median filter at point of local maxima’s.

Thanks in advance.

**Code :**

```
  A = [1 0 1 4.3 4.5 5 4.3 4.2 0 0 0 2 6.2 6.3 7 6.2 7.4 8  7.2 1 2 3 4 2];
  X= A;

  % For sin signal
  t= 0:0.01:10;
  A = sin(2*pi*t);
  X=A;
  t = 1:numel(X) ;

  [p l] = findpeaks(X);

  %  [pn ln] = findpeaks(-X);
  % yMedFilt = medfilt1(X,5,'truncate');

  y = medfilt1(X,2,'truncate');
  hold on 
  plot(p,'r','linewidth',3)
  plot(A,'b')
  hold off
```

I want is to have a straight line at every peak. Please have a look at attached picture . In the picture I am expecting output like 3rd diagram with straight line at every peak.

[image]

Comment: What is the rpoblem? finding the local maxima is not, as you already have it. Is it selecting the points? You just need to call the median filter to the output of `findpeaks`....

Comment: I have applied something like this but unfortunately I am getting some error for i= 1:numel(p)
 
y = medfilt1(p(i),2,'truncate');
end

Comment: yes the issue I am having is in selection of points where I need to apply median filter as I only want it to apply at local maxima’s and its neighbourhood.

Comment: "some error": Error, MATLAB is lazy today.   **what error**. Show the code that doesnt work

Comment: Error using sortingdatasets (line 16)
Input arguments must be 'double'.

Comment: You literally only need to do  `p=findpeaks(A); medfilt1(p)`

Comment: Thanks a lot andreas but unfortunately this is just providing me a straight line but what I want is to have a straight line at every peak. Please have a look at attached picture above. In the picture I am expecting output like 3rd diagram with straight line.

Comment: Imgur acting weird today, I cant see the image. However the answer I give you is what you asked, If the question is different please, make the post reflect that. Read [ask]

Comment: I have updated the question. I don't know why picture was not displaying. Hope now question is according to standered.

Comment: This is a classic example of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You are asking how to fix  a solution you think it may work, but your real question is completely different, as what you want is those flatten lines on peaks, has nothing to do with medians itself. Consider rewording the whole thing, explaining what you want to do, and then explaining what you tried to do and why it did not work

Comment: How is this different from your other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642098/assigning-values-to-the-neighbors-same-value-in-matlab?

Comment: This is different because in my other question I have made a window that searches out neighbours and apply the action what we want but in this question I have asked that is it possible for me to apply median filter on every peak instead of whole signal ? and if yes then how .